Custom Inherited Asset Type in Unreal Engine Editor Replaces Actual Asset Type
The problem:
I am trying to make a custom curve asset type in Unreal Engine and add it to the menu so that users can create the curve asset. My asset is called RecoilPattern, which inherits from UCurveFloat. The asset displays fine when I Right click in content browser and go to miscellaneous section. The problem is, when I go to the original Curve asset and create a Float Curve it is creating a Recoil Pattern.
How can I fix this?
For reference, here is my code:
RecoilPatternModule.h:
#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "Modules/ModuleManager.h"
#include "RecoilPatternActions.h"

class FRecoilPatternModule : public IModuleInterface
{
public:

    /** IModuleInterface implementation */
    virtual void StartupModule() override;
    virtual void ShutdownModule() override;
private:
    TSharedPtr<FRecoilPatternAssetTypeActions> RecoilPatternAssetTypeActions;
};

RecoilPatternModule.cpp:
#include "RecoilPatternModule.h"

#define LOCTEXT_NAMESPACE "FRecoilPatternModule"

void FRecoilPatternModule::StartupModule()
{
    RecoilPatternAssetTypeActions = MakeShared<FRecoilPatternAssetTypeActions>();
    FAssetToolsModule::GetModule().Get().RegisterAssetTypeActions(RecoilPatternAssetTypeActions.ToSharedRef());
}

void FRecoilPatternModule::ShutdownModule()
{
    if (!FModuleManager::Get().IsModuleLoaded("AssetTools")) return;
    FAssetToolsModule::GetModule().Get().UnregisterAssetTypeActions(RecoilPatternAssetTypeActions.ToSharedRef());
}

#undef LOCTEXT_NAMESPACE
    
IMPLEMENT_MODULE(FRecoilPatternModule, RecoilPattern)

RecoilPatternFactory.h:
#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "Factories/Factory.h"
#include "RecoilPatternFactory.generated.h"

/**
 * Factory that creates recoil curve assets
 */
UCLASS(MinimalAPI)
class URecoilPatternFactory : public UFactory
{
    GENERATED_UCLASS_BODY()
    
    // UFactory interface
    URecoilPatternFactory();
    UObject* FactoryCreateNew(UClass* Class, UObject* InParent, FName Name, EObjectFlags Flags, UObject* Context, FFeedbackContext* Warn);
    // End of UFactory interface
};

RecoilPatternFactory.cpp:
#include "RecoilPatternFactory.h"
#include "RecoilPattern.h"

URecoilPatternFactory::URecoilPatternFactory(const FObjectInitializer& ObjectInitializer) : Super(ObjectInitializer)
{
    SupportedClass = URecoilPattern::StaticClass();
    bCreateNew = true;
}

UObject* URecoilPatternFactory::FactoryCreateNew(UClass* Class, UObject* InParent, FName Name, EObjectFlags Flags, UObject* Context, FFeedbackContext* Warn)
{
    return NewObject<URecoilPattern>(InParent, Class, Name, Flags, Context);
}

RecoilPatternActions.h:
#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "AssetTypeActions_Base.h"

class FRecoilPatternAssetTypeActions : public FAssetTypeActions_Base
{
public:
    FText GetName() const override;
    UClass* GetSupportedClass() const override;
    FColor GetTypeColor() const override;
    uint32 GetCategories() override;
};

RecoilPatternActions.cpp:
#include "RecoilPatternActions.h"
#include "RecoilPattern.h"

UClass* FRecoilPatternAssetTypeActions::GetSupportedClass() const
{
    return URecoilPattern::StaticClass();
}

FText FRecoilPatternAssetTypeActions::GetName() const
{
    return INVTEXT("Recoil Pattern");
}

FColor FRecoilPatternAssetTypeActions::GetTypeColor() const
{
    return FColor(78, 40, 165);
}

uint32 FRecoilPatternAssetTypeActions::GetCategories()
{
    return EAssetTypeCategories::Misc;
}

RecoilPattern.h:
#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "Curves/CurveFloat.h"

class URecoilPattern : public UCurveFloat
{

};

RecoilPattern.cpp:
#include "RecoilPattern.h"


Have you tried asking here : https://forums.unrealengine.com/tags/c/29/unreal-engine?   (C++ tag here is more for questions about the C++ language)

@PepijnKramer Let me ask there as well, usually I don't get any responses there. Should I remove the c++ tag?

C++ tag is fine, because you do show C++ code. My guess is that most developers on SO don't know unreal engine that well. (Usually when I have questions on third party API's I first look for specific forums).

I have fixed this by changing my RecoilPattern.h to this:
UCLASS(BlueprintType, MinimalAPI)
class URecoilPattern : public UCurveBase
{
    GENERATED_UCLASS_BODY()
}

